# How to change color of a button when clicked using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone show me how to change a color of a button in bootstrap? I have a group of buttons and only the clicked button should be changing its color. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code, so we can at least have an idea of what you're working with?

Comment: What do you mean by clicked? Do you mean a link where the mouse is currently clicked on (active) or a link which has previously been clicked on (visited) or do you mean like a javascript/jquery click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without posting any code the best I can do for you right now if give you a simple JQuery function to change a button's color by switching classes.

**JS**:

```
// .btn is the class of the element you want to change color
$(".btn").click(function() {
  // Instead of directly editing CSS, toggle a class
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.btn {
  background-color: red;
}

.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**EDIT**:  As **ashin999** said, you actually have pre-defined classes in bootstrap (as you probably know) to change button stylizations.  So you could toggle one of those classes instead of a new `clicked` class.

Comment: You don't even have to do that. Since he's using bootstrap, just use a different btn css. So if it is btn-default, removecss, and addcss btn-success